# How to use Bootstrap Stylus with requireJS?

Tags: javascript, node.js, requirejs, npm, stylus

There are 12 js files in the Bootstrap Stylus folder (*affix, alert, button, carousel, collapse, dropdown, modal, popover, scrollpsy, tab, tooltip, transition*).There is a file in root folder called index.js but it looks a Node module file and I don't know how to require these files in requireJS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bootstrap Stylus should be compiled before, it'll generate the 'dist' folder that contains the files that will be used in requireJS.

You need to use terminal to navigate to boostrap-styl folder and run:

```
grunt dist
```